# How do I not pass null parameters from a subclass to its super class in Dart?

Tags: class, dart, inheritance

Say you have the following class and its subclass.

```
class ParentClass {
  final int a;
  final int b;
  ParentClass({this.a = 1, this.b = 2});
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  ChildClass({
    int? a,
    int? b,
  }) : super(a: a, b: b);
}
```

What I'd like to do is, when `a` or `b` is not given to the `ChildClass`'s constructor, to make `a` and `b` have their default values defined in the `ParentClass`, which are 1 and 2, respectively:

```
void main() {
   final child = ChildClass();
   print(child.a);   // expect to see '1'
   print(child.b);   // expect to see '2'
}
```

However, what I actually get from the above code is 'null' for both. Apparently, the `ChildClass` passes "null" to the `ParentClass` and it ignores the default values for its optional parameters in that case.

Is there a way I can avoid passing non-specified optional parameters from the `ChildClass` to the `ParentClass` or can keep the default value in the `ParentClass` even when 'null' is passed without manually specifying the same default values in the `ChildClass`?

Comment: There currently is no way to have a derived class reuse the default values from the base class method/constructor without duplicating them.  This is a common problem, and there have been [proposals to address it](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1492).  In the meantime you can mitigate it either by creating named constants for the default values or by making the types nullable and using `null` as the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this solve your issue but this is properly how I would do it:

```
class ParentClass {
  final int a;
  final int b;
  ParentClass({int? a, int? b})
      : this.a = a ?? 1,
        this.b = b ?? 2;
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  ChildClass({
    int? a,
    int? b,
  }) : super(a: a, b: b);
}
```